# boostrap theming -- How to remove duplicate styles?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, themes

This question is less of a code question and more of a best-practices question. I am working on a custom bootstrap theme based on https://github.com/HackerThemes/theme-kit. I have a working theme that I like, however, I am overriding some styles in the original Bootstrap theme. Even in the minified CSS, these are duplicated. For example, Bootstrap defines...

```css
.btn-danger:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ae130b;
    border-color: #a2120a;
}
```

...but my code also defines...

```css
.btn-danger:hover {
    border-color: #0000;
}
```

In the final stylesheet, both of these styles are present. The second style overrides Bootstrap and it *looks* just fine. However, this leads to useless code. First of all, is there a postprocessor of some sort that I can use with Gulp to eliminate these duplicates and consolidate them? Second, should I just fork the Bootstrap repository and modify the original SCSS directly?

Comment: Use SCSS, define variables which you would like to change and included them before bootstrap. Each variable in bootsrap has `!default` attribute. It means it can be overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you **@import**. Looking at [mytheme.scss](https://github.com/HackerThemes/theme-kit/blob/master/scss/mytheme.scss), the *entire* Bootstrap SASS is imported, creating full duplicate code in the final CSS.

Instead you can [pick specific SASS files to import](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#importing) and look at the [option variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults) which also effects what CSS is generated. For example, setting `$enable-grid-classes: false` will prevent duplication of the entire grid system in the generated CSS.